# Accesing my account on spotify and playing liked songs python

Tags: python-3.x, libspotify

I want to create a program that, if called, will access my liked songs playlist on Spotify and play either a random song or a song that has been called. I know that I should use the Spotify library, however, I don't really know how to achieve my goal, as most tutorials are about creating a new playlist or something of that nature, not accessing an already present playlist like liked songs.

Any advice will be appreciated:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the [pyspotify](https://pypi.org/project/pyspotify/1.11/) library. [This part of the documentation](https://pyspotify.readthedocs.io/en/latest/quickstart/#playing-music) goes in detail on how to play music and mess with playlists.